# Why does this throw "CryptoMaterial: this object contains invalid values" in C++, but works fine in python

Tags: c++, crypto++

I am interfacing with Mega.co.nz's API, using a python library as a reference and this code is throwing. The private key is of a temporary account.

When I only use the first prime it works, but if I include the second one it throws, yet everything works fine in the python code.

This code throws "CryptoMaterial: this object contains invalid values"

```
// g++ test.cpp -o test -lcryptopp
#include <iostream>

#include <cryptopp/rsa.h>
#include <cryptopp/integer.h>
#include <cryptopp/osrng.h>

using namespace CryptoPP;

const Integer c("10857166326382703760062779528766843368820930576598213227278471554906214169288262514203969639120532785228356073660117311791556795787311220009132632364495267243081665670086710276242234063736282452747089977833464270310556099739736793916154923086192702968111366046442015937417526298511445199340095898060147092158884693079554126699550560654798428433227449793922222881580173315635171540012289392792883134869370184160735204631001817822007869637755937740560912176149892518538187132538381475906064954503330035090788011376816518843886790979724470958150966813982521146398987188066116582925811581312709558507015381360737728282160");
const Integer n("13427557315502247597000078151163920443026153459996461135918747863095898679484680068841870307134991870634527490898047374333864169992533593470214214321618599580908993204307520436691605704402046321917552215500601059547120681142391461211832942043578807378527059669212765719156841060911214035328326209517003764423649629080809193207761562938380209994488934153009055462878017442054432223170713164757958714200660834201842865647297155663529615291314825578660639925675604438589594375258126020834604025620095899336598293228999530739615479725715448390873778015506002443516234879727296164834962067569248938506798206172807824155467");
const Integer d("11307416686738734818526381600980143530969392387365440956563156095238651519566046373761574995482098417376444202861513578386411932625291447132811969955047241752344415329943175104582404803706986376351622918316295629092312152540961230494175109089329522002970155510916013237184708261819969713960695755382740012146034212919647492076234405993178655740138052420647985859442037931597940897198569337697554456337486998070498389971468780232363941255237291940175758993311124407117751983734467699346428299766707608212611622303248258864115688090242455959830749262966169383160757942327094420226154106561552020347355716010319448907163");
const Integer p("100826948907457598414845964524448089304988432540271591225687687675999370502892903258891517574080931665624511494151970577170497712420499991942965423848183374943909439781466449525683097361603853112400332604761081878780250618758818492357490355994233490146112828080518628573284802902011591132699377690748913996743");
const Integer q("133174289820338768818359856956108213770008470949300663564909710605878037244519172983221279725814092327501516062026008560426937338300041407758960697270460830193354454791979178335037322285526761471721659139131141459697849499793713446217272909739442810866721995133352912243119263125394323211613915719804564581469");


int main(){
    AutoSeededRandomPool prng;

    InvertibleRSAFunction rsa;

    rsa.SetModulus(n);
    rsa.SetPrivateExponent(d);
    rsa.SetPrime1(p);
    rsa.SetPrime2(q); // Works fine if this line is removed
    RSA::PrivateKey privKey(rsa);

    Integer r = privKey.CalculateInverse(prng, c); // Throws here
    std::cout << "r: " << r << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But this python code works:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA

c = 10857166326382703760062779528766843368820930576598213227278471554906214169288262514203969639120532785228356073660117311791556795787311220009132632364495267243081665670086710276242234063736282452747089977833464270310556099739736793916154923086192702968111366046442015937417526298511445199340095898060147092158884693079554126699550560654798428433227449793922222881580173315635171540012289392792883134869370184160735204631001817822007869637755937740560912176149892518538187132538381475906064954503330035090788011376816518843886790979724470958150966813982521146398987188066116582925811581312709558507015381360737728282160L
n = 13427557315502247597000078151163920443026153459996461135918747863095898679484680068841870307134991870634527490898047374333864169992533593470214214321618599580908993204307520436691605704402046321917552215500601059547120681142391461211832942043578807378527059669212765719156841060911214035328326209517003764423649629080809193207761562938380209994488934153009055462878017442054432223170713164757958714200660834201842865647297155663529615291314825578660639925675604438589594375258126020834604025620095899336598293228999530739615479725715448390873778015506002443516234879727296164834962067569248938506798206172807824155467L
d = 11307416686738734818526381600980143530969392387365440956563156095238651519566046373761574995482098417376444202861513578386411932625291447132811969955047241752344415329943175104582404803706986376351622918316295629092312152540961230494175109089329522002970155510916013237184708261819969713960695755382740012146034212919647492076234405993178655740138052420647985859442037931597940897198569337697554456337486998070498389971468780232363941255237291940175758993311124407117751983734467699346428299766707608212611622303248258864115688090242455959830749262966169383160757942327094420226154106561552020347355716010319448907163L
p = 100826948907457598414845964524448089304988432540271591225687687675999370502892903258891517574080931665624511494151970577170497712420499991942965423848183374943909439781466449525683097361603853112400332604761081878780250618758818492357490355994233490146112828080518628573284802902011591132699377690748913996743L
q = 133174289820338768818359856956108213770008470949300663564909710605878037244519172983221279725814092327501516062026008560426937338300041407758960697270460830193354454791979178335037322285526761471721659139131141459697849499793713446217272909739442810866721995133352912243119263125394323211613915719804564581469L

rsa_decrypter = RSA.construct( (n, 0L, d, p, q) )

print( rsa_decrypter.key._decrypt(c) )
```

Comment: Perhaps there is a problem with the library you are linking against

Comment: FWIW I get the same problem using a freshly-downloaded and built cryptopp 5.6.2 plus your code; and using the same flags to g++ as cryptopp does, didn't help.

Comment: Thank you for checking, I suppose this could be library issue. I created a post on their mailing list, some developer insight would be nice.

Comment: It's open source so you could trace through and see where the problem is coming

Comment: I've got to the bottom of it now, initially I assumed your Python code was a Python port of this same library, but later realized it probably wasn't

Comment: Quite the opposite, the python is the original, and I'm porting this to C++.

Comment: When you have `{n,e}` (public key) and `{n,e,d}` (private key), then you should use `Initialize` function. Both `RSA::PublicKey` and `RSA::PrivateKey` provide the function overloads. After loading the key, be sure to call `Validate(3)` to validate them. GPG keys might give you trouble because GPG uses Lim-Lee primes, and not safe primes.

Comment: @jww Is it ok to call Initialize with {n, e, d}, and then add the primes? Crypto++ doesn't seems to provide an Initializer that accepts {n, e, d, p, q}. All these are for Mega.co.nz's API, so no GPG ... though I just found out they updated their previous library to something almost half-decent. Will do on the Validate, hadn't known that.

Comment: @Jacob - "Is it ok to call Initialize with {n, e, d}, and then add the primes?" - you don't need to. Given `{n,e,d}`, Crypto++ will solve for `p`, `q`, `d mod p-1`, `d mod q-1`, etc. There's also an `Initialize` that takes all 8 parameters. However, you will need to solve for the missing parameters before you can use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked the source. the exception is throw from `RSAFunction::Validate`, because `e` is not set.

However, setting `e` doesn't fix it, as then it is also thrown from `InvertibleRSAFunction::Validate` because `dp`, `dq`, and `u` are not set.

An RSA private key minimally only requires N, D. However, usually there are additionally the five integers P, Q, DP, DQ, QP. These extra integers are intermediate steps which make the calculation much faster. It is possible but very slow to do the calculation just using N and D. (You basically have to do log2(D) times as many calculations).

E is required for a public operation; but typically a private key is published as a key pair which includes E.

The Crypto++ private key operation also uses E however: it does some extra steps involving random data, which I presume is to prevent timing attacks.

I'd guess that the Python version works because it does not do this timing attack prevention; and it also computes any values that were missing. (They can all be computed from `N` and `D` as I mentioned, but this is slow).

Here is additional code to compute the missing values for yourself, this works for me:

```
rsa.SetModulus(n);
rsa.SetPrivateExponent(d);
rsa.SetPrime1(p);
rsa.SetPrime2(q);

// add this:
rsa.SetModPrime1PrivateExponent( d % (p-1) );
rsa.SetModPrime2PrivateExponent( d % (q-1) );
rsa.SetMultiplicativeInverseOfPrime2ModPrime1( q.InverseMod(p) );
rsa.SetPublicExponent( d.InverseMod((p-1) * (q-1)) );
```

Note that in general, private key files should contain all of these values - it's unusual (to me, anyway) that you would be sitting there with N,D,P,Q but not the others.

Comment: The python version uses 0 as e, I don't know if PyCrypto then changes that to something else. I suppose this could be considered a bug then?

Comment: I can assure you that `0` was not used as `e` in the generation of this key.  The private key operation does not require `e`, which explains why the Python version works. The crypto++ version validates the calculation against `e`. It could be considered a bug that crypto++ does not allow the option to skip this validation step; however I doubt you'd get a feature-request implemented because you must have known `e` when you generated the private key, so the simplest solution is just to supply `e` .

Comment: Sorry, I just realised that the `CalculateInverse` is not doing a simple decrypt. It reads some random data and uses `e` on that. I'd guess that this is to prevent timing attacks.  So, yeah you just have to supply `e`.  You must know what `e` is if you generated this key.

Comment: I don't currently have e, I did not generate the private key, but am deriving it. In the python implementation when it decrypts the private key it gets 4 values back, we use the first 3, but the last one is "52505211230281125330492135854881494511089773480999736899568101241839874894358114033385685553140115303504309908526210637053079294325784991624252409091315272783031871754133935016871728728301956017364743735174370106887585111281669776649209871940840002005892080841826672180275027076283456176151242227726330795644" I don't suppose that could be  e?

Comment: I applied the brain for 5 seconds and remembered that since 1 = ed mod phi(n), it's actually trivial to compute `e`. It turns out that `e` is 19 for your key (which is slightly weird).  The answer I get for `r` is now `39806...` using unmodified libcryptopp.a

Comment: Many thanks, everything seems to be working perfectly. This won't be rep farm, but I am very grateful.

Comment: NP. I just learned how to use Crypto++ also .. may come in handy in future coding